# Facebook Graph API Facebook Friends List Complete Android Example

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook 4.7 SDK and Graph Ver.2.5
I do not get Detail of a users friends

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
        if (jsonObject != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject friends = jsonObject.getJSONObject("friends");
                JSONArray array = friends.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"...Name:" + object.getString("name"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("MyApp", "...ID:" + object.getString("id"));
                    Log.d("MyApp", "...Name:" + object.getString("name"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
});
```

can someone give a full example of the facebook graph API friend list?

Comment: Hi Prashant, asking tutorial/example is offtopic here. Instead please describe your specific problem.

Comment: You are aware that your app can only get friends that are users of the same app as well, and have granted `user_friends` permission too – right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't Get user's Friends unless they given permission(user_friends) to your app. You can get only count of user's friend.